# Retrieving particular data from postgresql and storing them in sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite, postgresql

I am having a `postgresql database` which contains 10 `tables` with multiple records in each `table`.I retrieve particular information using `select` query.

**What i want**

I want only those selected results to be stored in my `android sqlite` database.I did convert the `postgresql` database to `sqlite` database using a tool named `SQLiteConverter version 1.9.5`,but it copies not only the structure of the tables but also all the records of each and every table.However i want only some selected result of the `postgresql` database to be stored in `sqlite` database.Is there any tool available which can store only some data but complete structure of `postgresql` into `sqlite`?

P.S:I searched for this issue but no other posts could make me clear in achieving this.

**EDIT**

Now i can always create tables in `sqlite` programmatically/manually with similar structure to that of the tables in my `postgresql`.Then i can retrieve data from `postgresql` and insert them into `sqlite`.But i wanted to do it using **Any tool if available.**

Comment: Do you need to do it in run time or this is just a one time task?

Comment: Once i get it done for one time,i would find a similar or a relative way of doing that whenever it is required again.Please check my edit too.